# Currency within celery task

Tags: python-2.7, concurrency, celery, celery-task

I am pretty new to python and celery.
My jobs are very heavy IO bounded, need to do http requests, querying redshift, mysql and writes to mysql.
We are thinking of using celery to continuously run jobs, but I am think if that possible to do concurrency within my celery task. Basically it is like each task can batch process a set of data, asynchronously making calls.
I was trying to use tornado gen.coroutine, but fails with celery with no clear reason. Would gevent or eventlet be good? could anyone please give some suggestion?
I really appreciate that, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to create multiple smaller celery tasks and use [Chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) to bind them together.

**Edit:** Since someone seem to not think linking to official documentation is good enough (only reason for downvote I can think of) I will paste the code from the docs here:

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def tsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)


>>> from celery import chord
>>> from tasks import add, tsum

>>> chord(add.s(i, i)
...       for i in xrange(100))(tsum.s()).get()
9900


>>> callback = tsum.s()
>>> header = [add.s(i, i) for i in range(100)]
>>> result = chord(header)(callback)
>>> result.get()
9900
```